# Compiling c code including allegro library 4 online

Tags: c, allegro

I'm wondering if there is a way to compile c code including allegro library 4 online.

I found only solutions which allow to compile c code and libraries that can be included with the directive #include <Name_library.h>, but allegro doesn't have a .h.

---

EDIT: sorry, as kamil suggested, allegro has .h files, but i don't know how to include them online.

Comment: `but allegro doesn't have a .h.` Really? There are [a lot of .h files](https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/tree/master/include/allegro5).

Comment: Hello @KamilCuk btw do you have any suggestion?